# pass string as mongodb command in php

Tags: javascript, php, json, mongodb

I am planning to run mongodb query from php platform text area as picture below where I want to write query like

```
 array('Chat_time' => array('$gt' => $start, '$lte' => $end))
```

[image]

and execute like

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->Forensic;
$coll= $db->mobile_
$user_code = $coll->find($_POST['txt_area']));
```

but cannot execute because I think when I convert query to string it cannot understand => as a command.

i have also tried like write in text area

```
{
    "Chat_time": {
        "$gt" => "xxx",
        "$lte" => "yyy"
    }
}
```

then executed following like but no luck

```
// json string to array
$query = json_encode($_POST['txt_area'], true);
$user_code = $coll->find($query);
```

what would be the best way pass this command as a string and php will understand and execute.